# Increase number of inodes on a disk

Tags: 12.04, disk-usage, disk-utility, inode

Can I increase number of inodes on a disk? How can I increase it ?
I am out of inodes just because of so many small files in disk.

Comment: Can you provide a few more details?  Which partition is this, the root filesystem or a separate partition containing your `/home` directory?  Is the filesystem ext4 or something else?

Comment: It is in /media drive and external drive.

Comment: @Aashu: If the answer below helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby I havent tried because i didnt have both option !! Please let me know if you have tried ?

Answer (score 3):

If backup and reformat is an option, you can use the option `-N` of `mkfs.ext4`:

> ```
> -N number-of-inodes
>       Overrides the default calculation of the number of  inodes  that
>       should  be  reserved  for  the filesystem (which is based on the
>       number of blocks and the bytes-per-inode  ratio).   This  allows
>       the user to specify the number of desired inodes directly.
> ```

I searched through `man tune2fs` but it seems that this number can't be changed on a existing filesystem (`tune2fs` is the command used to change an `ext2-4` filesystem).